# Changing text after click

Tags: excel, vba, click

how to adjust this code, so that it works for the whole column and not only for one cell?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
With Target
If .Address = Range("A11:A1").Address Then
Select Case .Value
  Case "Excel"
    .Value = "Word"
  Case "Word"
    .Value = "Outlook"
  Case "Outlook"
    .Value = "Excel"
  Case Else
    .Value = "Word"
End Select
End If
End With
Range("A2").Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thank you very much!
Jeame

Comment: Target.Column = 1 for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follows but you are setting up a recurring chain if you select A2 at the end and your target is column A. I have removed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target.Column = 1 Then 'example column A

    With Target

        Select Case .Value
        Case "Excel"
            .Value = "Word"
        Case "Word"
           .Value = "Outlook"
        Case "Outlook"
           .Value = "Excel"
        Case Else
           .Value = "Word"
       End Select

    End With

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Edit:

Following on from a change to requirements please see a re-write of your code. The Test sub is just for testing the event.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Test()
    Call Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(Selection, True)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Target.Column = 2 Then

        Dim var As Long
        Dim targetRange As Range

        var = Target.Row

        Set targetRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & var & ":B" & var) '2 columns of interest for row that was triggered

        With targetRange.Columns(2)

            Select Case LCase(.Value)            'i.e. column B's value. Add add change to lowercase so test always matches

            Case "active"

                targetRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
                .Value = "Finished"

            Case "wip"

                targetRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
                .Value = "Done"

            End Select

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, and how can I avoid the part

    Range("A2").Select
    
I would need to write my own text anywhere else in the spredsheet (except for that A column) and right now it is not possible.

Comment: Isn't the problem that you have a loop that keeps cycling through column A? Do you need a condition that selects outside of column A? Just comment that line out for A2

Comment: The only remaining problem is, if a random cell becomes active, then I change the value. Is it possible to add there some kind of lock or modify the code to double-click?

Comment: What do you mean? This responds specifically to column A. Can you give an example of what you would want to see happen?

Comment: f.e. in cell A1, I click on it, word "Excel" is filled in, then I write additional info into another cell of the row. Another day, I am listing in my spreadsheet and sometimes I have to mark the whole row 1 (then I get error). Or I am moving in my spreadsheet using arrows, and sometimes I  mark a cell from column A, which leads in changing the text. But it was supposed to change it only after one click on the mouse and not everytime the cell becomes active.

Comment: That  is not how the event works. You would need to keep a record of which cells had previously been the target cell perhaps by writing out to a different sheet. This sheet would be checked each time column A was triggered and only if cell wasn’t on list would action be carried out and that cell address would be written to the sheet so next time it would be ignored.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Too complicated solution for me. Below is the code, which should work similar but with double click.

Comment: Did it make more sense? I am sorry I threw all that jargon out without giving a proper example.

Answer (score 0):

Too complicated solution for me. Below is the code, which should work similar but with double click. Before I only did data valiation - listbox with two options. But somehow it does not work to me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Var = Target.Row

var2 = "b" + Var

If (Target.Column = 2) Then

If (Range(var2).Value = "Active") Then

var2 = "a" + Var
Range(var2).Interior.ColorIndex = 16
var2 = "b" + Var
Range(var2).Interior.ColorIndex = 16
Range(var2).Value = "Finished"

Else
Var = "b" + Var

If (Range(var2).Value = "WIP") Then
var2 = "a" + Var
Range(var2).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
var2 = "b" + Var
Range(var2).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
Range(var2).Value = "DONE"

End If

End If
End If
End Sub

 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot about that event! Indent your code properly as will help others to follow the flow. There is no need to repeat the interior.colorindex lines each time is there? You are applying to A & var : B and var which can means if you put that you can apply color to that or just resize A & var by 1 column.

Comment: Note you also answered a different  question from the one you posed which was what I answered :-)

Comment: I got to say I only search codes in Internet and copy them. So If you tell me "indent the code, resize A & var by 1 column, is there need to repeat interior.colorindex" I have no idea, sorry :/ Would it eb possible to adjust it for me?

Comment: I apologise that was thoughtless of me. I am on the mobile(away until Wednesday) but I will absolutely type up something and share a link so you can see what I mean :-)

Comment: As promised please find a re-write showing how I would re-write this using a variable and indenting. I avoided resize and simply set the original range to both columns A and B and then referenced the second column of this range later on. I have added as an edit version 2 to my answer.

Comment: Yes it works for me :) I would give you thump up, don t know how :)

Comment: I still don t have the privilege for it :)

Comment: Hopefully yes, thank you very much QHarr, I really appreciate your help! :)